# Deploy local glassfish restfull service to the internet

Tags: java, rest, http, netbeans, glassfish

I succesfully created an restfull webservice with netbeans and glassfish.
If I test the service locally (on localhost) i can POST, PUT, DELETE, and so on...

I also have my own domain on the internet...I pay for it every month.

It seems like a simple job but for some reason I can't find the solution to deploy my restfull webservice to that domain.

Like if I enter the URL of my domain with specific URL info that I would get an JSON respond.

I googled around...but it seems I'm looking at the wrong places.

So...
1) How can I deploy my local restful service to my domain online
2) is it possible trough netbeans and glassfish ?
3) Will I have to use an external application ?

thanx in advance

Comment: Does your web host support glassfish? Glassfish is your application server and your host would have to support glassfish. If so then spin up glassfish on your hosted site. Create a .war file on your local site. then deploy it to the hosted Glassfish server.

Comment: It seems my web host does not support Glassfish. I just asked support at my webhost their website. Are there any web hosts that provide this for free ? Like a trial ? or a limited amount of data ? All the information on the internet is so vague. They all talk about to run a resful webservice locally...If anyone knows a link or a step by step guide to deploy your webservice to your webhost it would be perfect! But thanx anyway @Iggy for your first response